# How we Configure AZURE Application Gateway for on-premises server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-application-gateway

I have apis on AWS iis server and I want to configure Azure application gateway for these apis, so that when I hit application gateway url from postman, the request is go on AWS iis server.

Comment: Please, could you provide more detail. Where are you stuck with the configuration? Are you seeing any errors? Networkwise, is the backend internal or public? If you are looking for general guidance on deploying and configuring Azure Application Gateways - this is well documented in the Azure docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-components ...

Comment: @holger thanks for the quick reply. 
I have my API’s running on in premise cloud IIS and want to access the API’s using Azure application gateway. 
Can we use Azure application gateway to access the services hosted outside Azure Cloud?